# Tipue Search results in a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, bootstrap-modal

I'm a rookie developer trying to render Tipue Search results in a Bootstrap modal. When putting everything together, the modal opens when the input field is clicked on (instead of waiting until a word is entered and clicked). This seems to be a conflict between Bootstrap and Tipue Search. Searching for hours on the web and Stack Overflow didn't produce a workaround. Please help. Thanks in advance.

URLs

- [Tipue Search demo, working perfectly without Bootstrap modals](https://tipue.com/search/demo/)
- [Tipue Search instructions](https://tipue.com/search/)

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Tipue Search, a jQuery Site Search Plugin</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link href="lib/bootstrap-4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="lib/tipuesearch/tipuesearch_set.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/tipuesearch/tipuesearch_content.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/tipuesearch/tipuesearch.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/lightbox-2.11.1/js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="lib/bootstrap-4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h2>A demo for version 7.1, My Local</h2>
   <p>Enter <code>tipue</code> or <code>blog</code>.</p>
   <form class="">
    <input 
     class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3" 
     type="text" name="q" 
     id="tipue_search_input" 
     data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#search-results" aria-label="Search">
   </form> 
   <div id="search-results" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="search-results-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="search-results-label">Search Results</h4>
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Testing 123</p>
       <div id="tipue_search_content"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#tipue_search_input').tipuesearch();
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

(function($) {

```
 $.fn.tipuesearch = function(options) {

      var set = $.extend( {

      'contextBuffer'          : 60,
      'contextLength'          : 60,
      'contextStart'           : 90,
      'debug'                  : false,
      'descriptiveWords'       : 25,
      'footerPages'            : 3,
      'highlightTerms'         : true,
      'imageZoom'              : true,
      'minimumLength'          : 3,
      'newWindow'              : false,
      'show'                   : 10,
      'showContext'            : true,
      'showRelated'            : true,
      'showTime'               : true,
      'showTitleCount'         : true,
      'showURL'                : true,
      'wholeWords'             : true
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {

           var tipuesearch_t_c = 0;                         

           var tipue_search_w = '';
           if (set.newWindow)
           {
                tipue_search_w = ' target="_blank"';      
           }

           function getURLP(name)
           {
                var locSearch = location.search;
                var splitted = (new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(locSearch)||[,""]);
                var searchString = splitted[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20');
                try
                {
                     searchString = decodeURIComponent(searchString);
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                     searchString = unescape(searchString);
                }
                return searchString || null;
           }

           if (getURLP('q'))
           {
                $('#tipue_search_input').val(getURLP('q'));
                getTipueSearch(0, true);
           }               

           $(this).keyup(function(event)
           {
                if(event.keyCode == '13')
                {
                     getTipueSearch(0, true);
                }
           });
```

Comment: Please add the code for  the `.tipuesearch()` function to your question.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the quick response. I believe the function is in tipuesearch.js 

`code

`

Comment: @Rob: The JS is a lot longer, but Stack Overflow has a character limit. I've also added URLs for reference.

Comment: PS: The conflict is between Tipue Search and Bootstrap modals. The Tipue Search result UX performs as expected outside of modals.